# Does Ubuntu MATE use gpu_mem?

Tags: ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu MATE on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and am not sure what value I should set the gpu_mem parameter in config.txt. Is there a way to calculate what that value should be for the best performance?

Comment: These links might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37506/minimum-gpu-mem-on-%cf%802 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15794/how-to-achieve-gpu-mem-8 In these questions they are using 16MB->32 MB and 8MB of RAM. Indeed your question might get better results if posted on the Raspberry Pi website.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I really appreciate a quick response. I guess I should try the Raspberry Pi website because those two references refer to older hardware. I really wanted to learn more about Ubuntu MATE relative to the gpu_mem on RPi3B+.